# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #'10/12/2015'(…)

Tags: javascript, click

this string of javascript gives me this error : Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #'10/12/2015'(…).

```
$("#10/12/2015").click();
```

what wrong ?

Thanks
Markus

Comment: Do you actually have an element with the `id="10/12/2015"`?

Comment: yes...but is a problem?

Comment: @MarkusWerner - only in that it makes it more complicated to select.   ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the / in the selector.

```js
$("#10\\/12\\/2015").val("aaaa");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="10/12/2015" />
```

jQuery explains it right on top of their [selectors documentation page](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: The selector is still invalid, as `1` cannot start a valid CSS `id` selector. jQuery accepts it, but that's a jQuery thing; it's not *valid*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but amazingly it still works fine in chrome... Selectors that start with numbers are fine in jQuery

Comment: No, they're not fine in jQuery. You've relying on an undocumented edge case. Although `$("#1")` works, because jQuery converts it into a `getElementById` call, this fails (as it should): `$("#1 div")` (e.g., selecting all `div`s within the `#1` element). The correct selectors are as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `/` character cannot be used literally in a CSS `id` selector. See the [rules for CSS identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). Additionally, the charater `1` cannot be used as the first character of an `id` selector.

If you really have an element with that date `id`, you can use an attribute selector:

```
$('[id="10/12/2015"]').click();
```

Alternately, `getElementById`:

```
$(document.getElementById("10/12/2015")).click();
```

Alternately, use the CSS escape for `/`, which is `\2F` or `\/`, and for `1`, which is `\31` (but not `\1`); of course, those backslashes need to be escaped to be put in strings, so:

```
$("#\\31 0\\2f 12\\2f 2015").click();
// or
$("#\\31 0\\/12\\/2015").click();
```

*(We need the spaces so that the CSS parser knows that the escape sequence has ended; the spaces are otherwise ignored; they are **not** interpretd as descendant combinators.)*

**Live Example** of all of those options, including using them in CSS to prove they work (and that `#1...` does not):

```js
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
  log("Clicked");
});

log("With an id selector:");
$('[id="10/12/2015"]').click();

log("With getElementById:");
$(document.getElementById("10/12/2015")).click();

log("With escaped 1 and slashes:");
$("#\\31 0\\2f 12\\2f 2015").click();

log("With escaped 1 and the other kind of escaped slashes:");
$("#\\31 0\\/12\\/2015").click();

function log(msg) {
  $("<p>").text(msg).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

```css
[id="10/12/2015"] {
  color: blue;
}

#\31 0\2f 12\2f 2015 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#\31 0\/12\/2015 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* Proof that the one starting with 1 is invalid: */
#10\/12\/2015 {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<p>Note that the button has blue text, a black border, and a 20px font. Those are applied by three diffent CSS rules, using the various selectors described in the answer. Note that it <em>isn't</em> strikethrough, proving that a selector starting with 1 is invalid.</p>
<input type="button" id="10/12/2015" value="Click Me">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```